# Алгоритм для поиска двух чисел разность которых по модулю будет кратна числу m

Tags: алгоритм

Есть N натуральных чисел, нужно найти такие два числа, у которых разница по модулю будет кратна числу m.

Подскажите, пожалуйста алгоритм для решения этой задачи. Мне ничего лучше полного перебора в голову не приходит. Хотя возможно стоит отталкиваться от остатков.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вот. А если надо только количество способов, то вместо индексов можно хранить количество.

```js
var a = [2,3,5,6,7,5]
var m = 10

var i = Array(m).fill().map(() => [])

for (var q=0; q<a.length; ++q) {
  i[a[q] % m].push(q)
}

for (var q=0; q+q<=m; ++q) {
  if (i[q].length && i[m-q].length) {
    if (m-q !== q) {
      console.log(`${q}+${m-q}: One of [${i[q]}] and one of [${i[m-q]}]`)
    } else if (i[q].length >= 2) {
      console.log(`${q}+${q}: Any two of [${i[q]}]`)
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Эээ... O(n+m), как я понимаю.

Comment: @Harry, ну да. А разве это плохо?

Comment: Почему? я этого не говорил, просто - правильно ли я понял алгоритм :)

Comment: @Harry, правильно. Если m большое, то можно что-нибудь со словарями похимичить и получить O(n+n*lb(n)), но автор никаких ограничений не привёл.

Comment: @Harry, а вообще идея - можно за O(n) сделать. Хотя нет - там всё равно массив размера m будет, так что не. Но если словарь.